# What function can I use to override the multisite maximum file size upload restriction?

Tags: uploads

What function can I use to override the multisite maximum file size upload restriction?

I have already maxed out the kb upload size and ensured that the max file upload size in php.ini is over 50mb, yet still I'm getting an error uploading an 11mb file.

[image: WP multisite max file size]

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at phpinfo and verified that `upload_max_filesize` is what you expect it to be?

Comment: Make sure you've also boosted `post_max_size` to at least the same or greater. Check out [the other precautions you should also take](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) when doing so.

Comment: post_max_size was it! Thanks @TheDeadMedic and Milo!

Comment: @TheDeadMedic you should put that as an answer, so the question can be marked as resolved. :)

Comment: @Chip Right on it ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you've also boosted post_max_size to at least the same or greater. Check out [the other precautions you should also take](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) when doing so.